# InvalidClassException error, not a typical error

Tags: java, spring, tomcat7

This error is not typical, normally I would just define the serialVersionUID locally and it would resolve the error.  This time I have it defined as such: `private static final long serialVersionUID = -4737353341161547579L;`

The problem really boils down to, I had placed the above line in the class initially and somewhere along the line it was deleted, never noticed.  Launched the code and got the error below.  I then realized my error and put the above line back in however I am still getting the same error.

How do I get this thing to go away?  Tomcat still runs without any problem, it almost acts like there is no problem at all.  It just fills up my log files.

```
SEVERE: Caught IOException decoding 612 bytes of data
    java.io.InvalidClassException: com.bannervision.core.Configuration; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -4737353341161547579, local class serialVersionUID = -3792553423588133868
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:604)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1515)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1769)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
        at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.transcoders.BaseSerializingTranscoder.deserialize(BaseSerializingTranscoder.java:112)
        at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.transcoders.SerializingTranscoder.decode0(SerializingTranscoder.java:98)
        at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.transcoders.SerializingTranscoder.decode(SerializingTranscoder.java:90)
        at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.XMemcachedClient.getAndTouch(XMemcachedClient.java:1965)
        at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.XMemcachedClient.getAndTouch(XMemcachedClient.java:1971)
        at com.bannervision.core.data.dao.BaseDao.getObjectById(BaseDao.java:243)
        at com.bannervision.core.data.dao.BaseDao.getObjectById(BaseDao.java:223)
        at com.bannervision.web.tag.ConfigurationNameTag.doStartTag(ConfigurationNameTag.java:28)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.dashboard_jsp._jspx_meth_bv_005fconfigurationName_005f1(dashboard_jsp.java:2902)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.dashboard_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f7(dashboard_jsp.java:2604)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.dashboard_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fotherwise_005f12(dashboard_jsp.java:2528)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.dashboard_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fchoose_005f13(dashboard_jsp.java:2455)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.dashboard_jsp._jspService(dashboard_jsp.java:475)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:172)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you try clearing out your memcached server?

Comment: Nope!  That worked like a champ...  I had no idea that was an option.  The more ya know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: com.bannervision.core.Configuration; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -4737353341161547579, local class serialVersionUID = -3792553423588133868

    at net.rubyeye.xmemcached.transcoders.BaseSerializingTranscoder.deserialize(BaseSerializingTranscoder.java:112)
```

Since the serialVersionUIDs don't match, these lines made me think the memcached server was holding onto a previous value that was conflicting.  Clearing the cache should solve the issue.